# Rails.cache.fetch before hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

Is there any type of before_filter equivalent that can be used with Rails.cache.fetch?

I'm using memcached in a test environment with multiple builds running and would like to setup a way to modify my keys based on an environment variable at a global level rather than touching every single call to Rails.cache.fetch.

I am open to suggestions if there is another way to solve this that I'm not currently aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `namespace` option or set the environment variables `RAILS_CACHE_ID` `RAILS_APP_VERSION` to append the cache key name.

From `rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb`

```
  # Expands out the +key+ argument into a key that can be used for the
  # cache store. Optionally accepts a namespace, and all keys will be
  # scoped within that namespace.
  #
  # If the +key+ argument provided is an array, or responds to +to_a+, then
  # each of elements in the array will be turned into parameters/keys and
  # concatenated into a single key. For example:
  #
  #   expand_cache_key([:foo, :bar])               # => "foo/bar"
  #   expand_cache_key([:foo, :bar], "namespace")  # => "namespace/foo/bar"
  #
  # The +key+ argument can also respond to +cache_key+ or +to_param+.
  def expand_cache_key(key, namespace = nil)
    expanded_cache_key = namespace ? "#{namespace}/" : ""

    if prefix = ENV["RAILS_CACHE_ID"] || ENV["RAILS_APP_VERSION"]
      expanded_cache_key << "#{prefix}/"
    end

    expanded_cache_key << retrieve_cache_key(key)
    expanded_cache_key
  end
```